# Preserve background images when isolating object

Tags: image, collections

In Blender 2.79 background images would remain visible when isolating a single object. Now that they are technically objects themselves, they also disappear when isolating a specific object or hiding everything apart from it (shift + H). This means I now have to go back to the Collections and make them visible again manually. This is rather annoying when I want to focus on modeling one object.

Is there a way in 2.8 to use "persistent" background images that won't be hidden along with everything else? Thanks.